# SQL Ranking Groups Ordered by Date Before Ranking Rule Is Applied

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ranking

I'm trying to get a rank over groups of integers when ordered by date. Some of the groups will have the same value but be separated by other groups. For this reason I can't use DENSE_RANK as is puts the integers of the same value together. The values of 10 below would belong to the same group in DENSE_RANK, I would like them to be in ranked group 2 & 4. Thanks for any help.

```
| ID | Date    | IntValue | DesiredRankResult |
| 1  | 01 Jan  | 10       | 4                 | 
| 1  | 02 Jan  | 10       | 4                 |
| 1  | 03 Jan  | 20       | 3                 |
| 1  | 04 Jan  | 20       | 3                 |
| 1  | 05 Jan  | 10       | 2                 |
| 1  | 06 Jan  | 10       | 2                 |
| 1  | 07 Jan  | 30       | 1                 |
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: i don't understand your logic at all. can you elaborate?

Comment: To assign ranks you need to define an ordering that will, in the case of your example, group Jan. 1 and Jan. 2 together, and group Jan. 5 and Jan. 6 together.  In your example these are both two adjacent dates.  Is it always true that only adjacent dates will be grouped, or could there be a gap in the dates?  if so, how large a gap?  Will there only be two dates in each group?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. We're on sql server 2008 r2. The result i need has to go in date order, then assign ranked groups over the intValue column, keeping values which are the same separate (in this example, 10)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with using `lead()` and a cumulative sum.  I think it looks like this:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when next_intval = intval then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by date desc) as DesiredRankResult
from (select t.*,
             lead(intval) over (partition by id order by date) as next_intval
      from t
     ) t;
```